# Running Python Module as a Service

Tags: python, flask, service, python-requests

I have a few modules that take time to load as they are somewhat memory intensive.  I've been using Flask to run them locally as a service I can make requests to when I need to execute some code e.g;

`url = localhost:5000/get_data_from_service`

(returns json I then parse into my current process).

The overhead of making the call and using the network to make the connection makes the process pretty slow... is there a better way to keep a class or module running that is faster and better suited for this type of task?